# Animations not working when switch to axes controls to screen button controls

Tags: android, animation, touch, unity-game-engine

I was doing moving  animation on my player and the code is as follows:

```
if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") > 0.5||Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") < -0.5) {
            myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * moveSpeed, myRigidBody.velocity.y);
            robotMove = true;
            lastMove = myRigidBody.velocity.x;
        }

        anim.SetFloat ("MoveX", Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"));
        anim.SetBool ("RobotMoving", robotMove);
        anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", lastMove);
```

as u can see above the controls are axes controls(keyboard) .

But I want to have these animations working on  control buttons which I created on screen !

I have this two butons as seen on pic:

[image: btns on screen]

I am using `eventrigger`  `onPointerDown` and attached **player** `gameobject` so as to call these functions:

```
public void moveleft(){
        myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (-moveSpeed, myRigidBody.velocity.y);
        robotMove = true;
        anim.SetFloat ("MoveX", -moveSpeed);
        anim.SetBool ("RobotMoving", robotMove);
    }

    public void moveright(){
        myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (moveSpeed, myRigidBody.velocity.y);
        robotMove = true;
        anim.SetFloat ("MoveX", moveSpeed);
        anim.SetBool ("RobotMoving", robotMove);
    }

    public void jump(){
        if (grounded) {
            myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (myRigidBody.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
        }
```

Now just like the axes controls the player is moving to some distance (not continuously if I keep holding) but The animation which was working on axes is **NOT WORKING IN THESE BUTTONS** !

can anybody tell why is it happening ?

Comment: Need to see code for buttons as well. If my guess is correct you're just doing "MoveLeft()" in the 1 frame you're clicking the button?

Comment: Yes ! ` moveLeft()` for left and `MoveRight` for right . the code is above @Fredrik

Answer (score 1):

to help others I solved my problem as follows:

See u can call **amin.setxxx**  only one either in `update()` or in some external `function()` call 
So what I did was that I placed all animations value putting in my moveLeft() and moveRight() functions as follows:

```
public void moveLeft(){



        myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (-moveSpeed, myRigidBody.velocity.y);
        robotMove = true;
        lastMove = myRigidBody.velocity.x;
        anim.SetFloat ("MoveX", -moveSpeed);
        anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", lastMove);
        anim.SetBool ("RobotMoving", robotMove);


    }

    public void moveRight(){



        myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (moveSpeed, myRigidBody.velocity.y);
        robotMove = true;
        lastMove = myRigidBody.velocity.x;
        anim.SetFloat ("MoveX", moveSpeed);
        anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", lastMove);
        anim.SetBool ("RobotMoving", robotMove);



    }
    public void stop(){

        robotMove = false;

        anim.SetBool ("RobotMoving", robotMove);

    }
```

I am calling this stop on `eventTrigger` `On pointerUp` of both left and right buttons to stop movement!